# why does tweepy api.search only returns maximum of 15 tweets per page when using result_type="popular"?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

The following code only returns 15 tweets, although count has been set to 100. (I replaced my desired hashtag with #hashtag.)

```
tweets = api.search("#hashtag", count = 100, tweet_mode="extended", result_type="popular")
```

There is no issue when I use `result_type="recent"`. It returns the 100 results.

My question is if there is something which I did wrongly? or if this is a limit of 15 from Twitter api itself for popular tweets' query?

The relevant Twitter's documentation says the number of tweets per page is by default 15 (nothing mentioned to show dependancy on result_type) but count should change it to max of 100.

link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

I'm also aware of pagination but this is not the answer, as I would like to get 100 Tweets per page and not in total.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @SaleemKhan If I remember correctly there is no solution to this. Twitter official API is far from perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
api.search(q="hello", count=1000)
```

or use `Cursor` as follows:

```
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='فقر').pages():
    for tweet in page:
      data.append([tweet.created_at])
```